# Como establecer un menú fijo en WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, menú

Quiero poner un menú y la cebecera fijo en *WordPress*. Ya encontré la menera pero se me corren hacia la izquierda y pierden el estilo por completo.

Este es el código que estoy poniendo:

```
/*main*/
.wpex-site-header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0; 
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está correcto, lo que debes asegurarte es que lo estas poniendo al DIV padre. Eso podes saberlo inspeccionando el codigo del sitio.
Tambien asefurarte que debajo de este codigo CSS no haya otros estilos que esten anulando tu codigo.
Para verificar eso podes agregarle !important a la linea de position.

```
/*main*/
.wpex-site-header { /*verificar que es el DIV padre del menu*/
   position: fixed!important; /*con esto obligamos a utilizar el fixed*/
   top: 0; 
   height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
}
```